# Certbot SSL certificate and http->https + www->non-www redirect to many times error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, redirect

I am running a rails app on linode. I am using nginx on ubuntu and have successfully created a certificate with certbot for both domains (www and non www)
`sudo certbot certificates` gives the following output

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.com
    Domains: www.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-02-19 20:17:51+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: www.example.com
    Domains: example.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-02-20 07:33:06+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

This is the content of my enabled nginx config file

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/example/shared/tmp/sockets/example-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/example/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/example/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/example/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  # server_name example.com;
  server_name 172.104.228.105;

  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**I would like to redirect all traffic to https://non-www.com. of https://heimlichhamburg.de**

The certificate was working for the www until I added another certificate for the non-www domain. Now I get a `redirected you too many times` error in the www and `This site can’t provide a secure connection` on the non-www domain.

UPDATED NGINX.CONF

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/wasgehthamburg/shared/tmp/sockets/wasgehthamburg-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/wasgehthamburg/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/wasgehthamburg/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/wasgehthamburg/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  # server_name example.com;
  server_name 172.XXX.XXX.105 www.example.org example.org;

  return 301 https://example.org.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2; #https of www*, 301 to right domain.
    server_name www.heimlichhamburg.de;
    #here the paths to your cert and key
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #do what you want to do here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can send all http to https, be it with www or without it.

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

If the host is www* and comes through https, redirect to https without www. By the way, here you will use the www.example.com certificate

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2; #https of www*, 301 to right domain.
    server_name www.example.org;
    #here the paths to your cert and key
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

And finally, if it comes with the right scheme, and with the right host, do whatever you want.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #do what you want to do here.
}
```

One of the problems I saw you had is that on example.com , on port 80, you were redirecting to scheme:/... , that means use the same scheme that arrives, so it was http constantly (redirect loop).

If you have any questions just ask them :D

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution and good explanation, it makes sense to me but apparently not nginx. after implementing your code (I have posted the updated nginx.conf in my original question) I can now not restart nginx server: ''sudo service nginx restart'' gives me: ''Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.''

Comment: What does sudo nginx -t say to you @Jan ¿?

Comment: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wasgehthamburg:47
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Did you change the example.com in the ssl_certificate for your path? I mean, my example has /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem , but that's not your path for sure

Comment: You need to put the ssl certificate in ssl_certificate and the key in the ssl_certificate_key @Jan

Comment: yes, changed example.org and www.example.org to my domain.

Comment: you need to put the ssl certificate in ssl_certificate and the key in the ssl_certificate_key - What do you mean by this. I thought creation and storage is handled by certbot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202900/discussion-between-jan-and-flaixman).